# How to get first file in subfolder while recursing through subfolders using windows batch

Tags: batch-file

I am currently trying to make creating par2 recovery files a little easier for myself. The following script goes through all the current-folder's subfolders and then creates par2 recovery files for all files in said subfolder.

```
FOR /R %%g IN (.) DO C:\WINDOWS\par2.exe c -r10 -s384000 "%%g\%%~ng.par2" "%%g\*"
del /q *.par2
pause
```

But now I have one issue, it uses the folder name as a filename for the par2 files but strips the "extension" like it would for a file. The folder names are something like "ConcertFootage1.avi_". That folder will then contain files like ConcertFootage1.avi.part01.rar and ConcertFootage1.avi.part02.rar and so on. Meaning I end up with par2 files like "ConcertFootage1.par2" where it should be "ConcertFootage1.avi.par2" in order to match the files in the folder correctly.

Now, even if it would *not* strip the "extension" from the foldername I'd still end up with "ConcertFootage1.avi_.par2" so I figured it would be best to just get the name of a file in the folder and use that as a base, meaning it would just strip the ".partX.rar" file-extension and that is exactly what I need.

I can't figure out how to do this in the "FOR DO" command though, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your question, that you try to strip two extensions from a filename.

You can do it with two `%~nX` flags.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /R %%g IN (.) DO (
  set "filename=%%~g"
  call :removeExtension result1 "!filename!"
  call :removeExtension result2 "!result1!"
  echo !filename! -- !result1! -- !result2!
)
exit /b

:removeExtension
set "%~1=%~n2"
exit /b
```

Comment: After also altering my winrar batch script to simplify the name of the archives, this did the trick, thanks :D